# H2-console in r2dbc-h2 driver

Tags: r2dbc, h2-console

I am using R2DBC-H2 driver, and my UR.L is `spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:h2:mem:///customer`

Using this configuration, SpringBoot starts fine, however, I can not access the h2-console.

Does anybody know why, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Do you get an error message that you can share? Please read [ask].

Comment: I'm not getting access to the h2 console with r2dbc-h2 driver, as well

Answer (score 1):

H2 Console depends on traditional JDBC drivers, not compatible with the Spring WebFlux stack.

If you are developing a WebFlux application, you can use H2 as a standalone database, and use H2 Console freely.

1. Following the official [Getting Started guide](http://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html#h2_console) to start H2 Database and H2 Console.
2. Set your `spring.r2dbc.url` to the database URL you are running in the first step.

NOTE: **Do not** use a Memory DB here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the source code of `H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration` correctly, the h2 console auto configuration from spring boot does not work in a reactive environment.

```
...
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = Type.SERVLET)
...
public class H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration {
```

You can confirm this by yourself by changing the type of your web application to SERVLET (for example, by adding `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency) which will activate the route to the h2 console (if enabled in the application properties). The h2-console route endpoint will start working again.

As the whole code seems very servlet-specific, I don't know how to properly fix this problem.